# How to hide a particular coloumn in Flexigrid by Default

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4, flexigrid

Please help, I want to hide a particular coloumn in flexigrid by default

Here is my Flexigrid which is sent in json

```
   $total = $this->countRec('id','pipo_orders',$where);
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" );
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
    header("Pragma: no-cache" );
    header("Content-type: text/x-json");
    $json = "";
    $json .= "{\n";
    $json .= "page: $page,\n";
    $json .= "total: $total,\n";
    $json .= "rows: [";
    $rc = false;
    $i=1;
    //while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach($result as $row) {
    $json .= "<input id=\"demo_box_".$i."\" class=\"css-checkbox csscheck\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".trim($row->id)."\"  /><label for=\"demo_box_".$i."\" name=\"demo_lbl_".$i."\" class=\"css-label\"></label>','";
```

Here is the json of the checkbox

```
$json .= "<input id=\"demo_box_".$i."\" class=\"css-checkbox csscheck\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".trim($row->id)."\"  /><label for=\"demo_box_".$i."\" name=\"demo_lbl_".$i."\" class=\"css-label\"></label>','";
```

I want to uncheck the first checkbox by default so that my first coloumn should always be hidden whenever the flexloads,

[image]

How can i do this or is there any other way to hide the first coloumn which has checkbox to be hidden by default. Please help

**Note : I don't want to hardcode in side the checkbox element as checked but i want to do it in the flexigrid way so that the entire coloumn itself disappear.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ever the coloumn it might be `hide: true` will do the trick.

In your FlexiGrid code to display the coloumn (Probably in your view)

```
{display: 'ID', name : 'id', width : 50, sortable : true, align: 'left', hide: true}
```